# Gunicorn 20.2 is better than ginicorn 3 for python? How to set workers?

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, ubuntu-20.04

I have a little issue installing gunicorn3 on ubuntu 20
When i try to install gunicorn3, ubuntu don't find any candidate but if i follow the gunicorn guide installing it with

```
pip install gunicorn
```

Gunicorn version 21.2 is installed.
Now... this version 21.2 is the only version that i can install

Problem... what is the command to set the workers?
Or there is any other way to install gunicorn3 on ubuntu 20?
Or do i need to erase and put ubuntu 18?